# How could I launch keyboard programmatically on Catalina (10.15)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard, macos-sierra, macos-catalina

I want to launch a screen(virtual) keyboard by NSAppleScript on macOS APP.

The following code is work finely before macOS Catalina (10.15). All need

permission is allowed.

```
NSString *theApplication = @"\"KeyboardViewer\"";
NSString *thePath = @"\"/System/Library/Input Methods/KeyboardViewer.app\"";

NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set HFSPath to ((POSIX file %@) as string)\n\
                    tell application \"System Events\" to ¬\n\
                    set isRunning to 0 < (count (application processes whose name is %@))\n\
                    if isRunning then\n\
                    tell application HFSPath to quit\n\
                    else\n\
                    ignoring application responses\n\
                    tell application HFSPath to activate\n\
                    end ignoring\n\
                    end if",thePath,theApplication];

NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
NSDictionary  *dict   = nil;
[script executeAndReturnError:&dict];
```

I got an error message (file not found「Macintosh HD:System:Library:Input Methods:KeyboardViewer.app)

How could I fix it?

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488965/macos-catalina-onscreen-virtual-keyboard-not-working)

Comment: They have a new application /System/Library/Input Methods/Assistive Control.app - but seems like you cannot launch it directly. It's configured to be launched as a LaunchAgent. Not sure how to trigger it programatically.

Comment: I just posted an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488965/macos-catalina-onscreen-virtual-keyboard-not-working/59745030#59745030

Answer (score 0):

There is no KeyboardViewer.app in OSX 10.15 up. You have to launch /System/Library/Input Methods/Assistive Control.app in OSX 10.15,

The following is my solution.

```
- (void)launchKeyboard
{
NSString *theApplication = @"\"Assistive Control\"";
NSString *thePath = @"\"/System/Library/Input Methods/Assistive Control.app\"";

NSOperatingSystemVersion minimumSupportedOSVersion = { .majorVersion = 10, .minorVersion = 15, .patchVersion = 0 };

BOOL isSupported = [NSProcessInfo.processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:minimumSupportedOSVersion];


NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set HFSPath to ((POSIX file %@) as string)\n\
                    tell application \"System Events\" to ¬\n\
                    set isRunning to 0 < (count (application processes whose name is %@))\n\
                    if isRunning then\n\
                    tell application HFSPath to quit\n\
                    else\n\
                    ignoring application responses\n\
                    tell application HFSPath to activate\n\
                    end ignoring\n\
                    end if",thePath,theApplication];


if(isSupported==YES)
{
    source =
    @"activate application \"System Preferences\"\n\
    tell application \"System Preferences\"\n\
    reveal anchor \"Virtual_Keyboard\" in pane id \"com.apple.preference.universalaccess\"\n\
    end tell\n\
    tell application \"System Events\"\n\
    tell process \"System Preferences\"\n\
    if (exists checkbox \"Enable Accessibility Keyboard\" of tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1) then\n\
    click checkbox \"Enable Accessibility Keyboard\" of tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1\n\
    end if\n\
    delay 1\n\
    end tell\n\
    end tell";
}

NSAppleScript *script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source] autorelease];
NSDictionary  *dict   = nil;
[script executeAndReturnError:&dict];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

do
{
    if(dict==nil)
    {
        break;
    }
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    NSString *message = [dict objectForKey:[[dict allKeys] firstObject]];
    
    if([message length]<=0)
    {
        break;
    }
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    
    if(alert==nil)
    {
        break;
    }
    
    alert.messageText = @"You have to allow automation for the app";
    [alert runModal];
    [alert release];
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane"];
    
    if(url==nil)
    {
        break;
    }
    
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
}
while (0);
```

}